# How to know the first anchor point in a path?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, anchor-point

I am in a middle of a website project to learn drawing for children. that project require me to know the starting anchor point for each path I draw. and if it is miss ordered I have to revers it.

I know there is an option for a compound path to reverse the orders of the anchor points over a selected path, and I am using it.

The reason I need to re-order of the path, that I am using an online service called [lazy_line_painter](http://lazylinepainter.info/) it's  free online service that convert my .SVG file into a path animated line.

This service draw the shape I converted into SVG in the same drawing order that is in illustrator, the very bottom layer will draw first, and the starting point will star the animation from, That's mean I want a certain order in illustrator to appear in a specific sequences, so when I drop it in Lazy line Painter it will draw in the same order I did in illustrator. That require me to reorder my layers and know the starting points in every path I draw in Illustrator.

My question is how to know if I need to reverse the path or not? and this gonna be an easy question if I know where is my first anchor point. so How to know the first anchor point in a path?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the **Stroke Panel** to add an arrowhead to the path. You can use that to see the beginning and end of a path, then remove the arrowhead.

As far as I'm aware, there's no direct method to find the starting anchor, only add some appearance to it so you can see it.

Comment: Offcourse in script this is pretty trivial on account that they are iterated in this order

Comment: For more usage of your method @scott I could use a free script [One Direction Paths](http://vectorboom.com/load/freebies/freescripts/free_adobe_illustrator_script_one_direction_paths/22-1-0-343) to reset the directions of all my path at once to a specific direction then change the direction of the paths I want to change one by one.